# EF4.3 linking viewbag item to viewmodel

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, razor, viewbag

I have the following action method in my Tournament controller:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id) {
        EditTournamentViewModel viewModel = new EditTournamentViewModel {
            Tournament = _tournamentService.GetTournamentByID(id),
            TournamentDivisions = _divisionService.GetTournamentDivisions(id).ToList()
        };

        ViewBag.SportID = new SelectList(_sportService.GetSports(), "SportID", "Name");
        ViewBag.CountryID = new SelectList(_countryService.GetCountries(), "CountryID", "Name");

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

The two viewbag items are select lists which will be filled up. When I inspect the page with firebug the name of the SelectList for `ViewBag.SportID` is `SportID`, which is what I would expect. But I want the value that is selected there to be entered in the `SportID` property of the `Tournament` property in my viewModel. So the name should be `Tournament.SportID`.

I don't understand how I can achieve this, I wasn't able to change the SelectList's name in Razor like this:

```
        <div class="editor-field"> 
            @Html.DropDownList("SportID", "Select a sport", new { name = "Tournament.SportID" } )
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(t => t.Tournament.Sport) 
        </div>
```

This is the code I have in my view:

```
        <div class="editor-field"> 
            @Html.DropDownList("SportID", "Select a sport")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(t => t.Tournament.Sport) 
        </div>
```

A solution I could take is instead of having a `Tournament` property in my viewmodel, I could copy over the individual properties and then use automapper but I would like to hear if there is a fix without having to do that (unless of course what I am doing is considered very bad practice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Tournament.SportID, ViewBag.SportID, "Select a sport")
```

?

(if you need the acual value of Tournament.SportId, for an update, for example, you can just look at the different constructors of SelectList and change it in your "ViewBag creation")

CORRECTION :

```
SelectList sportList = ViewBag.SportID;

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Tournament.SportID, sportList, "Select a sport")
```

Comment: If I try that it tells me `CS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TournamentCompanion.ViewModel.EditTournamentViewModel>' has no applicable method named 'DropDownListFor' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.`

Comment: Right, forgot that, you should redeclare your ViewBag value in a static way. Look at correction